# Pad numerical values in filename with three digit value using sed

Tags: bash, sed, file-rename

I am passing a filename into my bash script and cleaning the name using sed.   A few sample files would be:

```
Test 01.txt
Test v2 01.txt
```

I would like to get back:

```
Test 001.txt
Test v002 001.txt
```

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for f in $@
do

j=`basename "$f" ".???"`
BASENAME=`basename "$f" ".???"`
DIRNAME=`dirname "$f"`

j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/\///g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/_/ /g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/^\.//'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/\[[^()]*\]//g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/#//g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/+/\ /g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/\.\././g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/\&/and/g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/\ -/-/g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/-\ /-/g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/-{2,}/-/g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -r -e 's/\d+/sprintf("%03d",$&)/e'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/\.\././g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e "s/\'//g"`
j=`echo $j |sed -r -e 's/ {2,}/ /g'`
j=`echo $j |sed -e 's/\ \././g'`

if [ "$BASENAME" != "$j" ]; then
  mv -v "$f" "$DIRNAME"/"$j"
fi

done
```

Here is the problem line

```
j=`echo $j |sed -r -e 's/\d+/sprintf("%03d",$&)/e'`
```

The regex will work with rename but not with sed.

Comment: The multi-line was for my sanity/debugging process.  A sample filename would be: Test 01.txt   I want to rename it to Test 001.txt.

Comment: If `j` is initially the result of `basename`, what is this for: `j=\`echo $j |sed -e 's/\///g'\``. Only `basename /` puts out anything containing a slash.

Comment: That line was prior to using basename.  Just wasn't removed yet.

Comment: I would comment all those `sed` filters. I see you have `'s/\.\././g'` in two different places in the transformation chain. You're reducing two consecutive dots to one, and then doing it again. Spaces around a `-` character can be squashed with `s/ *- */-/`. Stuff like `s/  {2,}/ /` is useless use of `{m,n}`. Two or more spaces to a single space can be done using one or more, with `s/  */ /` or `s/ \+/ /`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
sed -r -e 's/\d+/sprintf("%03d",$&)/e'
```

use

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/sprintf("%03d",$&)/ge'
```

Comment: I normally don't approve of substituting perl for sed, but I think this is a perfect example of when that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed  -r 's/[0-9]+/$(printf "%03d" &)/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
Test 001.txt
Test v002 001.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, yes I understand about debugging with that method, and that was my guess.

It's almost as easy, and doesn't require a cleanup step later on to move the closing lines and the "'" char up and down a list like below to debug (as an alternative solution).

```
j=$(
  echo "$j" \
  | sed '
    s/\///g
    s/_/ /g
    s/^\.//
    s/\[[^()]*\]//g
    s/([^()]*)//g
    s/#//g
    s/+/\ /g
    s/\.\././g
    s/\&/and/g
    s/\ -/-/g
    s/-\ /-/g
    s/-{2,}/-/g
    s/\.\././g
    s/'"'"'//g
    s/ {2,}/ /g
    s/\ \././g
' \
| awk '/[0-9]/{
   match( $0,/[0-9][0-9]*/ )
   begin=substr($0,1,RSTART); end=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH,length($0))
   num=substr($0,RSTART,RSTART+RLENGTH)
   printf("%s%03d%s", begin,num+0, end)
  }'
)
```

**Edit** It may be possible to double-triple up on the escaped single quotes, i.e. `\\'` or `\\\'`, but I'm going with the tried and true `s/'"'"'//g`.

Unless you're using the original bourne shell on Solaris, AIX, HP, or other old-line unixen, join the 1990s ;-) and use the `$( ...)` construct for command substitution. Backquotes have been deprecated since at least 'The New Kornshell programming Language', published 1995.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I will move my script in this direction.