# Zero-pad numbers in file names that are not padded

Tags: bash, shell, sed, renaming

I have a directory full of files named

```
image_1.jpg
image_2.jpg
...
image_10.jpg
...
image_335.jpg
```

Now I want to use a command line tool which expects the images to be alphabetical ordered. But the alphabetical order of these filenames is: `image_100.jpg image_101.jpg ... image_10.jpg image_11.jpg ... image_1.jpg ...`.

How can I rename these files using a short shell / bash command? I've found that `sed` is possible a way to go, but this tool is a mystery to me.

Comment: Maybe your tool just uses the order given? For example, if you invoke it as `sometool image*.jpg` then you can just do `sometool image_{1..335}.jpg` instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896070/pad-numerical-values-in-filename-with-three-digit-value-using-sed

Comment: @thatotherguy no the tool simply expects the working dir to be full of ordered images :(

Comment: Which OS are you doing this on? Do you have a `rename` command?

Comment: `ls -v *` may be your friend but using `ls` to pass file names is always fraught with othe problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash:

```
for i in *; do if [[ $i =~ (image_)([0-9]{1,2})(\.jpg) ]]; then printf -v num "%03d" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; echo mv -v "$i" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${num}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"; fi; done
```

If everything looks okay, remove `echo`.

Tested with a directory with those file names:

```
image_100.jpg
image_101.jpg
image_10.jpg
image_11.jpg
image_1.jpg
image_2.jpg
image_334.jpg
image_335.jpg
image_3.jpg
```

The created commands:

```
mv -v image_10.jpg image_010.jpg
mv -v image_11.jpg image_011.jpg
mv -v image_1.jpg image_001.jpg
mv -v image_2.jpg image_002.jpg
mv -v image_3.jpg image_003.jpg
```

Result:

```
image_001.jpg
image_002.jpg
image_003.jpg
image_010.jpg
image_011.jpg
image_100.jpg
image_101.jpg
image_334.jpg
image_335.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found a solution, not using a shell command but by writing a simple ruby script:

```
input = Dir.glob("image*.jpg")

input.each do |name|
  parts = name.split /[_\.]/
  number = parts[1]
  number = number.rjust(3, '0')
  new_name = [parts[0], '_', number, '.', parts[2]].join
  File.rename(name, new_name)
end
```